# Netbeans Platform Installer and JOGL

Tags: jogl, netbeans-platform

I'm trying to build an application that uses both Netbeans Platform and JOGL.  So far, it runs fine from within  Netbeans, but once I try to create an application that can run externally, I get some problems.  The application will start (judging from the splash screen), but a window never displays, and I never get an error message.  As soon as I remove the JOGL module (leaving only straight Swing code), everything works fine.

Project Setup:
1 Library Module for JOGL, including the dll's (for Windows 7 64 bit only), in the library/modules/lib folder

1 Module for a window displaying a GLJPanel, rendering a simple image with an animator

1 Module with a simple form in Swing

Has anybody seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: apparently the trick in this case (using native libs when building Netbeans Platform executables) is **placing the native libs in the project's root folder**.

If this were not about netbean platform executables, a more generic comment is to make sure the native libs (dlls) are picked up correctly. Try adding the

-Djava.library.path=/path/to/libs option when you run it.

Comment: I'm really not sure if they are being picked up at all.  I don't know how to add the -Djava.library.path argument when running, as I'm running an exe, not a jar file, or source code.

Comment: Try putting the dlls in the root of your project folder. See this tutorial: http://wiki.netbeans.org/SlickSet